# Is there an email header that will avoid responses from most auto-responders?

Tags: email

I have a few scripts that automatically send out small email notifications when necessary.  I get a small number of auto-response messages (e.g. out-of-office or vacation) back from these.  Is there a header I can add to the email that will indicate to (well-behaved) auto-responders that I'm not interested in any response?

See also [this related StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154718/precedence-header-in-email).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Adding a "`List-Id`" header or a "`Precedence: list`" header should solve the problem for well behaved auto-responders.  The behavior comes from the original vacation program for UNIX.  Among other things it will not respond to an email that appears to come from a list.  You would probably be better off with the List-Id header line than taking chances with the precedence setting but try both.

Comment: RFC3834: `Because Precedence is not a standard
      header field, and its use and interpretation vary widely in the
      wild, no particular responder behavior in the presence of
      Precedence is recommended by this specification.`

Answer (score 12):

I believe `Precedence: Bulk` is the canonical setting, but the number of people whose autoresponders obey it is miniscule.  Fact is, the vast majority of autoresponders are badly behaved.

Comment: RFC3834 `Because Precedence is not a standard
      header field, and its use and interpretation vary widely in the
      wild, no particular responder behavior in the presence of
      Precedence is recommended by this specification.`

Comment: Yes, that's what I said.

Answer (score 6):

No, there nothing that always works.

#There's standards

sending wuth a null return path (empty envelope sender, SMTP `MAIL FROM:<>`)
should prevent autotoresponders (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-4.5.5)

> Implementers of automated email processors should be careful to make
> sure that the various kinds of messages with a null reverse-path are
> handled correctly.  In particular, such systems SHOULD NOT reply to
> messages with a null reverse-path,

setting an Auto-Submitted header should also work
(https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3834#section-2)

> Automatic responses SHOULD NOT be issued in response to any
> message which contains an Auto-Submitted header field

#And then there's Microsoft...
section 2.2.3.2.14 in https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-oxcmail/e489ffaf-19ed-4285-96d9-c31c42cab17f
(URL subject to expire at Microsoft's whim)[MSOXCMAIL] 2.2.3.2.14

says

> #2.2.3.2.14 Suppression of Automatic Replies
> To set the value of the PidTagAutoResponseSuppress property (section 2.1.3.2.20) to -1,
> indicating that all automatic replies to the message are to be suppressed, clients SHOULD write an X-Auto-Response-Suppress header with the value "All".

...

> MIME readers SHOULD<116> map individual elements of an X-Auto-Response-Suppress header
> to bits in the value of the PidTagAutoResponseSuppress property according to the table. If both
> the X-Auto-ResponseSuppress and Precedence headers are present, the
> PidTagAutoResponseSuppress property value SHOULD be 0xFFFFFFFF but MAY<117> be
> 0x00000000. If the value of the X-Auto-Response-Suppress header is other than as specified in the table in section 2.1.3.2.20, MIME readers SHOULD<118> ignore the entire header.

Those little notes are most revealing

> <116> Section 2.2.3.2.14: Outlook 2010, Outlook 2013, Outlook 2016, and Outlook 2019 do not read the X-Auto-Response-Suppress header.

> <117> Section 2.2.3.2.14: Exchange 2003 uses this value for the PidTagAutoResponseSuppress property ([MS-OXOMSG] section 2.2.1.77).

> <118> Section 2.2.3.2.14: Exchange 2003, Office Outlook 2003, and Office Outlook 2007 ignore the X-Auto-Response-Suppress and Precedence headers.

so presubamly `Exchange Server 2007` or newer want `X-Auto-Response-Suppress`
and Outlook wants `Precedence`

Note that this is ignoring  https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3834#section-2

> (Because Precedence is not a standard
> header field, and its use and interpretation vary widely in the
> wild, no particular responder behavior in the presence of
> Precedence is recommended by this specification.)

The best move is probably to do all four, or as many of these as are possible.

Comment: Thanks for this info @Jasen - very helpful. Are there any risks you are aware of with using a null return path, in particular with regard to spam filters? I manage a booking system that issues confirmation emails. These are not bulk messages, but naturally have no use for auto-replies. Avoiding spam filters is a constant battle for us.

Comment: Yeah, spam filters may block or drop that especially if the domain uses SRS or other VERP on all their outbound.  use a real return path, if possible one that you can monitor (so, not hosted on a rate-limited service like gmail)

Comment: Thanks for the advice! We do use VERP, now you mention it.

Comment: i mean the destination domain of the emails: The recipeint sever may decide that it looks like a forged bounce and reject it on that basis.